Raising/lowering extracted contour layer using QGIS
Is there a way to raise/lower an extracted contour layer?
I've scoured the properties panel and have tried to raise/lower "elevation" menu, but when I make changes there nothing happens to the contour labels.

The symbology will honor the order of the layers as shown in the Layer panel. The labels however seem to always render on top.
To hide labels in specific maps, you can use duplicate layers and themes, like this:

Duplicate the layer (right-click > duplicate layer)* and its style;
In the duplicated style, turn off the labeling;
Create two themes: one using the unlabeled layer, and one using the original one;
Use the different themes for specific maps, depending on the desirability of labels**.

*If you duplicate the layer this way, the duplicate will be a 'pointer' to the original layer. When editing the original data, the duplicate will follow.
**You can use this functionality in many ways, and create layers with many duplicates. I currently use them for different symbologies, label hiding, label content, label placement strategies, and filtering of feature subsets.
